# Xcode error when trying to execute C program

Tags: ios, c, xcode

I'm new to using XCode since this is my first OS X laptop. I have found it very convenient and somewhat easy to use and wish to continue using it. I get an error when I try to execute a class in a project. I can still program using the main.c class (i.e. remove the existing code and replace it with new code), but if I create a file, I can execute nothing, not even the main.c file. After I delete the 2 files that you create when press new file (name.c, name.h), the main.c can be built again. Here is the error I get, thanks for any help.

http://tinypic.com/r/2620h8m/8
http://tinypic.com/r/ionfx5/8

Comment: You need to study the "C" language, get a good book on it. There can only be on `main` function. There are no classes, just two code files.

Comment: So I have to create a new project for every small program I create? This is my 1st day with C lol excuse my retarded questions. Thought this was like Java, just create individual classes all executing different code

Comment: A good start would be to understand what a program is, also what a class is.